# Is there a way to animate transitions on floating objects using ONLY css?

Tags: css

Please don't suggest plugins like Masonry or Isotope, I'd like to do it without any javascript if possible.

Here's an example:
[tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/ztaou5Jf)

Is it possible to make the transition of the second (black) block down smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not when the objects are floating. You would be able to do this if they were absolutely positioned within the parent container ([see example](http://tinkerbin.com/A4ERigBq)), but then you lose the automatic fluid layout.